# QML ListModel deep copy

Tags: qml, qtquick2

The question is very straightforward:

does Qml `Listmodel` `append` method a deep copy of a `Qobject*` parameter ?

It seems to me that the answyer is yes, but i cannot find any documentation about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not do a deep copy for a `QObject*`, as a `QObject` can not be copied, as its copy constructor is private.
It will copy the pointer itself, but not the `QObject` behind the pointer.